# Save multiple dropdown value into one column in SQL database

Tags: sql, .net, asp.net-web-api

I want to save multiple values into one column in database using ASP.NET Web API.

In the front end, I am able to select multiple values from dropdown, but while saving into database, it's throwing an error.

Eg. if I have four selected value in dropdown (val1, val2, val3, val4), I want all values stored in one column, separated by comma in database.

Comment: INSERT INTO `table_name`(col1)
   VALUES (val1, val2, val3, val4)??

Comment: Can we see what you've tried and the error message?

Comment: ***DO NOT DO THIS!*** Seriously - this is the worst possible design for a relational database, and it violates even the **first normal form** of database  design. Do **NOT** do this! Instead, use the **relational features** and store four values as four rows in a separate table - **that** is a proper, relational design.

Comment: @marc_s is correct, this is a seriously bad thing to do. It will make querying your data very difficult. It will make your database be slower. Databases are optimized for relational tables. It will be harmful in every possible way. DO NOT DO THIS!!!!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

```
string[] values = new string[] {val1, val2, val3, val4} ;

string joinedVal = string.Join(",", values) ;
```

But seriously this is almost certainly a bad idea and will come back to bite you if you ever want to work with the data.